# env variables set from the code are not available in imported modules in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to set environment variables in the code so they are available in imported NPM modules?

A short example:

`index.js`:

```js
const supportsHyperlinks = require('supports-hyperlinks');

process.env.FORCE_HYPERLINK = 1;
console.log(supportsHyperlinks.stdout); // false; process.env.FORCE_HYPERLINK is undefined inside
```

`node_modules/supports-hyperlinks/index.js`:

```js
'use strict';

function supportsHyperlink(stream) {
    const {env} = process;

    console.log(env.FORCE_HYPERLINK); // returns false

    if ('FORCE_HYPERLINK' in env) {
        return !(env.FORCE_HYPERLINK.length > 0 && parseInt(env.FORCE_HYPERLINK, 10) === 0);
    }

    ...
}

module.exports = {
    supportsHyperlink,
    stdout: supportsHyperlink(process.stdout),
    stderr: supportsHyperlink(process.stderr)
};
```

It seems that each NPM module has its own `process.env` object.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oMtlkuS — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: It seems that the behavior is different between importing a local module or importing an NPM package. Let me update my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a timing issue and nothing to do with using a module installed via NPM or not.

---

> ```
> const supportsHyperlinks = require('supports-hyperlinks');
> ```

First you require the module causing it to run.

---

> ```
> module.exports = {
>     supportsHyperlink,
>     stdout: supportsHyperlink(process.stdout),
>     stderr: supportsHyperlink(process.stderr)
> };
> ```

Then you populate the exports, including `stdout` with the return value of a function.

That function logs `env.FORCE_HYPERLINK` **which is currently not set**.

---

> ```
> process.env.FORCE_HYPERLINK = 1;
> ```

Then you set `env.FORCE_HYPERLINK`

---

> ```
> console.log(supportsHyperlinks.stdout); // false; process.env.FORCE_HYPERLINK is undefined inside
> ```

Finally you read the value that was previously assigned to `stdout`.

---

You need to call the function **after** you set the environment variable.

You could set it as a getter function on the exported object so it is called every time you access `.stdout`.

```
module.exports = {
    supportsHyperlink,
    get stdout() { return supportsHyperlink(process.stdout) },
    get stderr() { return supportsHyperlink(process.stderr) },
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change it to be a getter function because it is an external code from an existing NPM package.

Comment: Then you need to set the environment variable before running Node.

Comment: I can't; settings this environment variable depends on a complex condition calculated in my `index.js`.

Comment: Then split that out into a seperate program.

Comment: Actually, I just swapped `process.env.FORCE_HYPERLINK = 1` with `const supportsHyperlinks = require('supports-hyperlinks')`, and everything started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code relies on the `env`, but you set it in the code which has not been set when the app starts.

I'd suggest using `cross-env` or `dotenv` to set the `env` before all your code runs.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that's not possible. I'm trying to overcome a bug in `supports-hyperlinks` that doesn't recognize Windows Terminal as a terminal that supports embedded hyperlinks. My code is a part of a public CLI tool so I cannot set `env` variables statically in a file using `dotenv`.

Comment: @VladimirPanchenko Have you tried `cross-env`, the `env` can be set in your environment, that is the terminal.